# Wordpress Media Library not refreshing with new upload

Tags: wordpress

when we upload a file to the Media Library at
https://OurSite.org/wp-admin/upload.php the file doesn't show up onscreen immediately. It looks like nothing has happened. But when we refresh the browser, the file appears.

We thought perhaps this was a SiteGround caching issue, so added wp-admin/ to the exclusion list and used the Supercacher testing tool to confirm that
https://OurSite.org/wp-admin/upload.php was now excluded.

We also purged the SiteGround cache, but still the Media Library does not dynamically refresh when uploading a file. Wordpress version is 4.7.2 and CiviCRM version is 4.7.13

We have the same Wordpress version installed on a different host and it is working properly. We confirmed that it is caused by CiviCRM when we disabled the CiviCRM wordpress plugin. We looked for possible collisions of libraries, but it is not evident why CiviCRM is affecting any of the output on that page.  We're looking for insights from someone with additional Wordpress expertise.

Comment: Have you switched to a default theme to see if you theme is responsible?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a complete answer yet, but I had the same problem with SiteGround and it is to do with file permissions. See [Adding images in CKEditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21019/adding-images-in-ckeditor) for what I changed.

Also see my recent question [file permissions with hosted wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/file-permissions-with-hosted-wordpress) about the wider issue.