# Picture selection for CiviEvent name badge - KCFinder not useable

Tags: civievent, kcfinder

I am trying to configure name badges for CiviEvent events.

When trying to configure the pictures, for upper left/right corner, an unformatted page opens and clicking on links like upload returns an error.

[image]
[image]

Any hint how to fix this? I checked civicrm.settings.php to ensure that the correct path is used and that the permissions for the upload folder are correct.

Any other way to get the pictures up and placed on the right place?

CiviCRM 5.8.1
Wordpress 5.0.2

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the CiviMobile extension which injected script code before the original page content and before the OnLoad event for loading the JQuery library. After removing this plugin, the upload page comes up properly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to a problem I had a while ago with the picture editing not being available and most of it was down to the default permissions with the WordPress CiviCRM install not being correct. See [Adding images in CKEditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21019/adding-images-in-ckeditor). That may be the answer or at least point you in the right direction. I didn't post an answer, but should go back and do that. My solutions were in the comments.

Comment: Thx Mick, I tried it with 755 on the directory of kcfinder and 644 below but end up with an access denied when access.
Are you by chance able to retrieve a database entry of such a name bade so I could just configure the filename of the graphics directly via mysql?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem resolved via DB..
I get the table civicrm_print_label and I update part of the field "data"
"image_1":"http://www.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/Logo_GrAG_130x130_v1_0.jpg"
with the new file name