# unable to upload image file when creating a message

Tags: wordpress, mailing, images, upload

This question was asked before, and marked answered at:
[Unable to upload or view files through the CKEditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/unable-to-upload-or-view-files-through-the-ckeditor)

but the adjustment recommended did not solve the problem for me.

After upgrading to CiviCRM 5.22.1, I am no longer able to upload image files when working on defining a mailing.
With previous versions of CiviCRM I could Upload an image using the dialog box Upload Tab that appears when clicking the image icon.

On the 1. Define Mailing tab on
,,, /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/mailing/151
clicking the image icon opens a dialog box titled: Image Properties
It has 4 tabs: | Image Info |  Link | Upload | Advanced

Selecting the Upload Tab shows Choose File:

I can enter an image file to import.
But when I click the button "Send it to the Server"

I get a JavaScript popup alert that says: "incorrect server response"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like a resource URL issue as no civi menu is loading, etc. If I think I am on the right site it still shows 5.9.1. Have you run upgrader? Seeing 'Blocked loading mixed active content' so SSL issue.

Comment: Using chrome inspect console: When clicking "Send it to the Server" the following message appears. I check the reference cited. The message and the reference didn't help me, but might help somebody.
ckeditor.js?r=Lo5W8:19 [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#filetools-response-error

Comment: (anonymous) @ ckeditor.js?r=Lo5W8:19
d @ ckeditor.js?r=Lo5W8:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js?r=Lo5W8:11
CKEDITOR.warn @ ckeditor.js?r=Lo5W8:18
...

more like this but too long for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fixing the root issue, but I tend to think the best practice here is to load media within the Wordpress Media Gallery and link to it in CiviMail. Content is best put in the CMS. That way, you can use the media for say a blog post and for CiviMail. It's more efficient.

I think some day being able for Civi to query the WP media gallery would be most desirable.

Comment: "Civi to query the WP media gallery" - that's a really nice idea @andy-burns. Do you mean in CKEditor? FWIW if Civi defaulted to TinyMCE on WP, this would become much more straightforward.

Comment: Your suggestion to put the image in the media library is what I have been using as a work around. It works for me.